# Creating a sh script that runs a sql script with user defined parameters

Tags: bash, sh, greenplum

I am new to creating sh scripts. I am trying to create a .sh script that would take in user input and execute a SQL script by updating the parameter as given by the user.

The user input is just limited to a single parameter. The parameter to be passed is a job id -

```
Enter job id: 321
Confirm job id: 321
```

This job id is used in different parts of the SQL code, an excerpt of the code is below -

```
CREATE READABLE EXTERNAL TEMP TABLE JOBID_USER (
    cola numeric,
    colb bigint,
    )
LOCATION (
    'gpfdist://.../JOBID_USER_INFO_321.txt' --the job id is at the end of the file
)
FORMAT 'text' (header delimiter e',' null '' escape 'off') 
ENCODING 'latin9';
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE AS 
SELECT * FROM schema.deliverytable_321 -- the job id is used to identify a table
        WHERE JOB_ID= 321              -- the job id is used as a condition
        AND asset_1 = 9999
DISTRIBUTE RANDOMLY;
```

The DB is Postgres and I execute the script manually in Greenplum. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a simple idea.
wrote your sql queries in a file named sample.sql or something else :
**Note: Replaced JobID to MY_VAR**

```
CREATE READABLE EXTERNAL TEMP TABLE JOBID_USER (
    cola numeric,
    colb bigint,
    )
LOCATION (
    'gpfdist://.../JOBID_USER_INFO_MY_VAR.txt' --the job id is at the end of the file
)
FORMAT 'text' (header delimiter e',' null '' escape 'off') 
ENCODING 'latin9';
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE AS 
SELECT * FROM schema.deliverytable_MY_VAR -- the job id is used to identify a table
        WHERE JOB_ID= MY_VAR              -- the job id is used as a condition
        AND asset_1 = 9999
DISTRIBUTE RANDOMLY;
```

now use this script named like sql_executor.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash 
sed "s/MY_VAR/$1" sample.sql | psql -U [USERNAME] -d [DATABASE_NAME]
```

Usage :

```
sql_executor.sh 321
```

Comment: Do you really need `echo sample.sql`? AFAIN this pipes the sting 'sample.sql' and not the file. I'd recommend to let `sed` open the file directly:
`sed "s/MY_VAR/$1" sample.sql | psql -U [USERNAME] -d [DATABASE_NAME]`.

Comment: ohhh , yes yes , you right . actually not need to use echo command .  @BobaFit

Answer (score 1):

This is how you get input interactively in bash

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "Enter job id:"
read -r JOBID
printf "Confirm job id:"
read -r JOBIDCONFIRM

[ "$JOBID" != "$JOBIDCONFIRM" ] && {
        echo "Jobid inputs have not the same value"
        exit
}

echo "Now you can use your jobid $JOBID anywhere in double quoted strings, like this sentence"
```

### EXPLANATION:

**printf**: echo a string
**read [varname]**: wait for user input and assign it to [varname] variable

Comment: @franzisk: Thanks for the parameter script. Though, can I call the SQL script which has all $JOBID in all the required places? like how we would normally run a psql file
psql /myscript.sql

Comment: Yes. First just echo the generated script, to check if everything is ok. If it's ok then pipe your script do pgsql (./script.sh | psql -U [USERNAME] -d [DATABASE_NAME]) .My answer is just to suggest how to ask the user for an input, assign it to a variable, use the variable in a string.

Answer (score 1):

psql has "variables" that you can use for parameters. For example:

```
cat foo.sql 
select :param1
```

The colon in the SQL file indicates it is a variable.

To use this variable, you just pass a value to it with psql.

```
psql -f foo.sql -v param1="'bar'"
 ?column? 
----------
 bar
(1 row)
```

To execute this from a bash script, you can use a bash variable.

```
cat runme.sql 
#!/bin/bash
param1="$1"
psql -f foo.sql -v param1="'$param1'"
```

Note: be sure to chmod runme.sql so that you can execute it.

```
chmod 755 runme.sql
```

And now running it.

```
./runme.sql foobar
 ?column? 
----------
 foobar
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hi Jon, Yes this works too. Though, my sql script would have the parameter nested within a table name sometimes. for e.g. schema.table432m where 432 is the parameter. then ```where colA= 432 and ..```, ```..create table as job_id432 ...```
The parameter could be placed in different string positions across the sql code.

Comment: you can use multiple variables with psql. psql -v param1 -v param2, etc. So the bash script can create the table name parameter and then pass it to psql.